# Android open custom url scheme from facebook app

Tags: android, google-chrome, facebook-android-sdk, custom-url

I am uses `intent-filter` to open custom urls with my app, and it works fine..

When im trying to open my custom url's from google chrome browser or facebook native app post (in private message its works good) its doesn't work and open it as website.

My code:

```
<intent-filter>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <data
    android:host="mydomain.co.il"
    android:scheme="http" />
  <data
    android:host="www.mydomain.co.il"
    android:scheme="http" />
  <data
    android:host="www.mydomain.co.il"
    android:scheme="myscheme" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: you probably lack a datatype ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably its the same bug as mentioned in the following reference post, its stated that its  [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181186), you can see a workaround there for this issue.

[OAuth and custom scheme result in a "ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568792/oauth-and-custom-scheme-result-in-a-err-unknown-url-scheme-in-chrome)